# Use MongoDB _id field as composite field with multiple fields

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, bson

Since every collection in mongodb has a default index on the _id column, I wanted to leverage it for my scenario as below.

I have my collection as below,

```
{
    "_id":{
            "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-08-24T23:22:20.201Z"),
            "departmentname" : "sales",
            "city":"NJ"
        }

        //Other fields in my collection
}
```

With this structure I am able to query as below,

```
db.getCollection('test').find(
{
    "_id" : {
        "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-08-21T23:22:20.201Z"),
        "departmentname" : "sales",
        "city":"NJ"
    }
}
)
```

But, when I query by one or more fields in which are part of _id column  as below,

```
db.getCollection('test').find(
{
    "_id" : {
        "timestamp" : ISODate("2016-08-21T23:22:20.201Z")
    }
}
)
```

(OR)

```
db.getCollection('test').find(
{
    "_id" : {
        "departmentname" : "sales"
    }
}
)
```

(OR)

```
db.getCollection('test').find(
{
    "_id" : {
        "departmentname" : "sales",
        "city":"NJ"
    }
}
)
```

I do not see any documents returned

When I checked with .explain() I see that it has used Index but did not find any documents.

Also, I would like to do date range queries on timestamp field along with query on one or more fields in the _id column like below,

```
db.getCollection('test').find(
{

    "_id.timestamp" : { 
        "$gte": ISODate("2011-08-21T23:22:20.201Z")
    },
    "_id.departmentname" : "sales"
}
)
```

But, I do not see any documents returned. When I run .explain() I see it has used colscan and not index.

Can someone help me on the right way to query by one or more fields on my _id column.

Thanks,

Sri

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try following query, in first case:-

```
db.getCollection('test').find(
{
    "_id.timestamp" :  ISODate("2016-08-21T23:22:20.201Z")
})
```

And this for multiple fields:

```
db.getCollection('test').find(
{
    "_id.timestamp" :  ISODate("2016-08-21T23:22:20.201Z"), 
    "_id.departmentname" :  "sales", 
})
```

Comment: Please refer documentation of find as well. Glad it helped.

Comment: When I run .explain() wth the query, it appears index on _id field has not been used. It has made a collection scan and not used index. Why would that be so?

Comment: @javauser See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-single/#create-an-index-on-embedded-document for important information about MongoDB behavior when indexing an embedded document.  Basically, "field order matters and the embedded documents must match exactly." I think creating a compound index would be more suitable for your use case.